# How to use declare functions in NestJS

Tags: nestjs

I was using this repo with Node.js:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-essential

But now, with NestJS I'm having problems to make the import properly.
The original lines are:

```
var pg = require('pg');
require('pg-essential').patch(pg);
```

And using NestJS I can use: `import * as pg from 'pg';`

for the `pg` require, but how can import the second require?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```js
import { patch } from 'pg-essential';
patch(pg);
```

Importing a named exporting and calling the function, instead of doing a chained require function.